# Trigger causes Null Pointer Exception

Tags: trigger, null-pointer

I have created a trigger, and when I test it in my application, I get the following error:

`CreatePolicy: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.CreatePolicy: line 132, column 1`

This is the code it complains about:

```
for(Policy__c rec: newPolicies){
                for(PolicyERN__c ern: mapSourceToERN.get(mapNewToSource.get(rec.Id))){
                                PolicyERN__c newPolErn = ern.clone();
                                newPolERN.Policy__c = rec.Id;
                                newERN.add(newPolERN);
                 }
        }
```

Can I do anything about this? Tia.

Comment: Its indicating that your mapSourceToERN map does not contain the key you are looking for.  Perhaps you can show us how you are populating this map.  An easy way around the error is adding an IF() statement that says uses the containsKey() function to make sure your map contains the key you are looking for.

Comment: have you instantiated your mapSourceToERN before the policy loop?

Comment: Please post your test method.

Comment: Can we also see how  `newPolicies` is populated?